# Issue with xarray DataArray Indexing in Different Environments

Tags: python, numpy, python-xarray

I'm encountering a strange issue with xarray DataArray indexing in different environments.
The first environment (environment A) is with Python 3.7.3, xarray 0.17.0 and numpy 1.17.4)
The second environment (environment B) is with Python 3.10.10, xarray 2022.6.0 and numpy 1.23.3

I have two code snippets that involve an xarray DataArray named `loc` (boolean) and an numpy array named `distances`. In one environment, the indexing behaves as expected, while in another environment, it returns an empty array.

Here's a simplified version of the code:
First Code Snippet (Not Working in Environment A, working in Environment B):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import xarray as xr

time = pd.date_range('2014-08-09', periods=11)
loc = xr.DataArray([False, False, False, False, False,  True, False,  True,  True, False, False], coords={'time': time}, dims='time')
distances = np.array([243.53, 218.88, 204.39, 176.83, 158.21, 98.97, 115.43, 88.61, 98.72, 118.28, 115.93])

result = distances[loc]
print(result)
# I expect printing [98.97 88.61 98.72]
```

and
Second Code Snippet (Working in both environments):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import xarray as xr

time = pd.date_range('2015-03-01', periods=39)
loc = xr.DataArray([False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
                  False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
                                 True,  True,  True], coords={'time': time}, dims='time')

distances = np.array([327.18, 326.60, 307.71, 306.17, 305.41, 305.50, 283.12, 281.91, 237.74, 239.87, 243.06, 220.90, 217.88, 216.07, 215.42, 191.55, 192.03, 193.86, 196.98, 178.90, 174.65, 171.88, 170.55, 147.01, 146.60, 147.88, 150.90, 155.53, 132.83, 128.44, 126.02, 125.56, 127.11, 102.04, 68.17, 33.67, 54.38, 56.46, 62.59])

result = distances[loc]
print(result)
# prints [54.38 56.46 62.59]
```

What could be causing this discrepancy? I'd appreciate any insights or suggestions to debug this issue. Thank you!